# toggle hidden : unhidden not working with JS in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/bDQt7/1/

Toggle hidden : unhidden doesn't work, and I can't figure out why?

html

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('menu');">Toggle</a>

<div id="top">
    <div id="menu" class="hidden">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.unhidden {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine, you were loading the JS in the wrong place: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bDQt7/2/

Comment: Case closed. The problem was a 13inchs situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Wrap code in `body` or `head` below your html.

<kbd>[**Working fidde**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDQt7/3/)</kbd>

[image]